# Why can't I memcpy an int to a char[] without getting the address of the int?

Tags: c, pointers, char, int, memcpy

This might be a duplicate, but I haven't found any other question dealing with my exact situation (yet).

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
int n = 12;
char s[sizeof(n)];
memcpy(s, (char *)n, sizeof(n));
printf("%d", s);
```

Basically, I want to copy `n` into `s` without having to get the address of `n`. When I run this, it gives me a segmentation fault. This, however, works:

```
printf("%d", (char *)n);
```

So I know that the problem is in the memcpy call. Why can't I memcpy an int into a char[] like this?

Comment: `memcpy` expects an *address* where it can find some data to copy.

Comment: Why is taking the address a problem?

Comment: you cannot because when you are using a library function, you have to abide by the signature of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a segmentation fault because what you're trying to do is not what your code states.

```
int n = 12;
char s[sizeof(n)];
memcpy(s, (char *)n, sizeof(n));
```

You *wanted* to say:

> "copy the `sizeof(int)` bytes representing the value of `n` into `s`".

But `memcpy()` is about copying memory objects, not values. An object *resides* at a given address, and *contains* a given value. Taking `n` gives the value, taking `&n` gives the address.

And the construct `(char *)n` tells the compiler to interpret the **value** of `n` as the **address** of a `char`, so what you **are** saying is:

> "copy the `sizeof(int)` bytes **at the address contained in `n`** into `s`."

Since `n = 12`, you are reading from address `0x00000012`... which is most likely not a legal address to read from (hence the segfault).

By taking the address of `n` before casting *that* (instead of the *value*) into `char *`, your statement matches your intent:

```
int n = 12;
char s[sizeof(n)];
memcpy(s, (char *)&n, sizeof(n));
```

> "copy the `sizeof(int)` bytes **at the address of `n`** into `s`".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to take the address of `s` since the name of an array in this context evaluates to the address of the first element. Since the integer `n` is not an array, that doesn't apply, which is why you must take the address.

Of course you can use an `int` array too, to get around this, but it's extremely silly and a very bad idea in general:

```
int n[1];
char s[sizeof n];
memcpy(s, n, sizeof n);
```

This works because `n` now evaluates to `&n[0]`, i.e. the address of the first (and only!) element in the array.

Note that `sizeof` is not a function, it does not need parentheses for this usage.